# Linter Error: Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'video:type'

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-opengraph

I'd like this page to display the video player instead of a thumbnail on facebook. Currently, facebook will display the player in some instances, other times it will not.

Here's the link:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.plant4thegospel.com%2Fresources%2Fvideo%2F78-why-gospel-grace

I'm getting these errors.

```
Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'video:type'.
Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'video:secure_url'.
Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'video:width'.
Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'video:height'.
Parser Mismatched Metadata: The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input property =>content pairs that were not seen in the parsed result: 'og:video:type => application/x-shockwave-flash, og:video:secure_url => https://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=44753220, og:video:width => 640, og:video:height => 360'
```

Any ideas??

Here's my OG tags...in order.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Why Gospel Grace Church? - Videos"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie"/>
<meta property="video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
<meta property="og:video" content="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=44753220"/>
<meta property="video:secure_url" content="https://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=44753220"/>
<meta property="video:width" content="640"/>
<meta property="video:height" content="360"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.plant4thegospel.com/resources/video/78-why-gospel-grace"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/311/086/311086152_960.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Salt Lake City needs churches like Gospel Grace Church. Salt Lake City is a major metropolitan area packed with one million people--prosperous and needy, religious and irreligious, young and old, international and domestic--searching for hope apart from Jesus. Over the next few weeks, we'll be posting four videos that describe our hopes for Gospel Grace Church and the city."/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="512988036"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="122489644534138"/>
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_gb" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Plant For the Gospel" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change the

```
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie"/>
```

to

```
<meta property="og:type" content="video.other"/>
```